# Ordered Dict of columns to Rows for CSV?

Tags: python

Suppose I have an ordered dict in the following format:

```
{ 'col0': [ 'a','b',...,'z' ],
  'col1': [ ... ],
  ...
}
```

However, the `csv` library, when writing a dictionary out to a file, expects a list of rows:

```
{ 'col0': 'a', 'col1': 'b' }
{ 'col0': 'c', 'col1': 'd' }
```

How does one transition from an `OrderedDict` as described above to a set of values corresponding to the format that `csv` expects in the best possible way? (i.e., simple and fast)

Comment: Did you try reading into Pandas then writing?

Comment: @Chris why would I read into Pandas and write? Pandas is a 3rd party lib that is only a wrapper around python + numpy, and a P** in the A** to use.

Comment: None of what you have just said is true.  I would suggest trying to read the dict into pandas and write to csv.  It will be easier and faster than native Python

Comment: Even if pandas isn't an option for you, you haven't provided enough of a sample of your input data to reproduce your output, What are the values in your col1 that produce that output? Are there more columns to be concerned with, or only col0, col1?

Comment: @G.Anderson why not answer my question?  Here, I have already figured it out

Comment: @Chris actually, what the OP states is true. `pandas` is a 3rd party library designed for various data analytics use-cases, and it's giant sledgehammer to swat a fly for something the standard library can handle. It won't necessarily be faster to materialize a giant data-frame simply to write a csv.

Comment: @donlan can you give an exampe of the code that uses the `csv` module that gave you that `dict`? The csv module provides two main `reader` objects, one that gives you an iterator over simple `tuples` like ('a','b')` and the other an iterator of `dict` objects like this: `{ 'col0': 'a', 'col1': 'b' }`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh, nope, already forgot that I read it in in col-major form.  Thanks again though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```
csv.writerow(ordered_dict.keys())
csv.writerows(zip(*ordered_dict.values()))
```

Answer (score 2):

This might get you the expected output:

```
func = lambda y: {'col'+str(i): y[i] for i in range(len(y))}
x = {func(dict(i)) for i in dict}
```

You can use this to convert `dict` into a csv file:

```
import csv

dict = {'a': '1', 'b': 2, 'c': '3'}

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f:
    for key in dict.keys():
        f.write("%s, %s\n" % (key, dict[key]))
```